# Add vendor prefixes to CSS with Java tool?

Tags: java, css, sass

We have a Java web application in which we want to expose a SASS-driven templating engine. For prototyping and possibly later in production, we are using Bootstrap 4. In theory, the pipeline is easy. Forgetting about Java for a second:

- make a _custom.scss
- include _custom.scss before _variables.scss (within bootstrap.scss)
- compile the CSS based on bootstrap.scss

Easy in theory. So far, we can hand this off to Java. An interface collects the contents of what will become _custom.scss (from a form, for example), and then saves an appropriately-formatted file. Then we can leverage one of the SASS-compiling tools (LibSass, for example) to create a new CSS file. There are even tools to minify that CSS file and save it out to the web server.

However, Bootstrap specifically (and our own framework potentially, if we go that way) does not supply vendor prefixes in the scss source files. The Bootstrap authors rely on build (via NPM script) to run an auto prefixer for their own builds. For other parties, there are tools readily available in Node (including Grunt and Gulp if you go that way), Webpack, Browserify, and other JavaScript-driven technologies.

The only port of autoprefixer I came across for Java was this one: https://github.com/mwanji/autoprefixer4j

This one has not seen an update in 3 years, making me wonder if it is able to perform all the current/latest vendor prefixing that may be required. Is there a better tool or a better way to accomplish the goal? Are my fears unfounded and autoprefixer4j is considered a fine (and current) way to do it?

There are other options of course, but these usually involve firing up another technology (like Node.js) and issuing commands to it. The Java team strongly prefers not having the application firing off command-line tools unless they have to.

Comment: Looking into the linked repo the only deprecated part seems to be the embedded `data.json`. Actual version here: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/blob/master/data.json